# query two tables where one row is like another row

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like, mysql-5.6

I need to join two tables where one row value should be inside the other row.

```
t1
f1,f2

t2
f11,f22

query
select * from t1 join t2 on f1=f11
where
f22 LIKE %f2%
```

How do I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.f1 = t2f11
where t2.f22 LIKE concat('%', t1.f2, '%')
```